# how to correctly modify the iterator of a loop in python from within the loop

Tags: python, loops, iterator

what I basically need is to check every element of a list and if some criteria fit I want to remove it from the list.

So for example let's say that

```
list=['a','b','c','d','e']
```

I basically want to write (in principle and not the actual code I try to implement)

If an element of the list is 'b' or 'c' remove it from the list and take the next.

But

```
for s in list:
    if s=='b' or s=='c':
        list.remove(s)
```

fails because when 'b' is removed the loop takes 'd' and not 'c' as the next element. So is there a way to do that faster than storing the elements in a separate list and removing them afterwards?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easier way is to use a copy of the list - it can be done with a slice that extends "from the beginning" to the "end" of the list, like this:

```
for s in list[:]:
    if s=='b' or s=='c':
        list.remove(s)
```

You have considered this, and this is simple enough to be in your code, unless this list is really big, and in a critical part of the code (like, in the main loop of an action game). In that case, I sometimes use the following idiom:

```
to_remove = []
for index, s in enumerate(list):
    if s == "b" or s == "c":
         to_remove.append(index)

for index in reversed(to_remove):
    del list[index]
```

Of course you can resort to a while loop instead:

```
index = 0
while index < len(list):
   if s == "b" or s == "c":
       del list[index]
       continue
   index += 1
```

Comment: jsbueno thank you very much. I feel a bit ashamed for not thinking that. Thanks again!

Comment: I actually wanted a loop within a loop and your last example was perfect. thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

Its better not to reinvent things which are already available. Use [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) functions and lambda in these cases. Its more pythonic and looks cleaner.

```
filter(lambda x:x not in ['b','c'],['a','b','c','d','e'])
```

alternatively you can use list comprehension

```
[x for x in ['a','b','c','d','e'] if x not in ['b','c']]
```

Comment: Actually, the list comprehension in your second example is "more Pythonic" than the  filter and lambda combination.

Comment: thanks but I needed to put one such loop into an other and this way things can become really messy.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what itertools.ifilter is designed for.

```
from itertools import ifilter

ifilter(lambda x: x not in ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

will give you back a generator for your list. If you actually need a list, you can create it using one of the standard techniques for converting a generator to a list:

```
list(ifilter(lambda x: x not in ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']))
```

or

```
[x for x in ifilter(lambda x: x not in ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with creating a copy of the list you can do it like this ([list comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)):

```
[s for s in list if s != 'b' and s != 'c']
```